# Redefining some simple \cee type command in package {mhchem}, to avoid using the package

Tags: mhchem

Is it possible to define a simple macro replacing `\cee` in package `{mhchem}` (since the package  leads to errors)? Thanks.

Comment: Instead of trying to define a command similar to how it is defined in a package, it may be worth investigating why including/using the package results in errors in the first place. Fixing the incompatibiltiy or probably a syntax error may be a lot easier than trying to rewrite something from scratch.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the documentation of `mhchem`, the `\cee` command is outdated and you should use `\ce` instead: "Deprecated commands like `\cf`, and `\hyphen` and `\cmath` were removed completely. `\cee` was removed — just use `\ce`. " So depending on the version of `mhchem`, you tried to use, switching from `\cee` to `\ce` could already help you avoid error messages.

Comment: Lastly, it would also be helpful if you could prepare a compplete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error you get, along with the error message you recieve upon compiling your code.

Comment: -leandriis  thanks. I'm trying to  use someone else's tex. As far as I can see, the only chemical package is

Comment: \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} and the only use is like \cee{ <=>} ,  \cee{ ->}  which is some type of displaying. \ce{ } did not improve, I still get a long uncopiable error  message. But removing the \cee's and package fixed the problem :)

Comment: What does "someone else's tex" mean? The tex installation on someone else's device or some tex code provided to you by someone else?

Comment: some tex code provided to me by ArXiv

Comment: Take this code and prepare a small but complete test file from it that still reproduces the issue you have. Add this test document to your question as well as the error message you get upon compiling the test document on your system.

Comment: Please also clarify your goal: Is it to compile this exact document on your system or are you just interested in a similar output? If it's the atter, there may be better/other/more modern ways to achieve the output you're interested in. In this case, please also provide an image of the output you would like to replicate.

Comment: The goal was to compile approximately  this document,  and I already solved my problem by removing the \cee{ command. Sorry for not having figued this alone :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option `[version=1]` to load an earlier version of the package. This fixes the error, and you do not need to define a command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=1]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\cee{CO2 + C -> 2 CO}
\end{document}
```

Another alternative could be to use the `\ce` command in `version 4`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{CO2 + C -> 2 CO}
\end{document}
```

Picture of output using version 1:

[image]

And if you ***really*** want to define your own macro:

---

This is how it is defined in the legacy option og the `mhchem` package:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\cee[1]{\mhchem@cee{#1}}
```

I guess `\mhchem@cee{#1}` is defined by this:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \mhchem@cee #1  % \__mhchem_cee:n
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

which uses the `expl3` package.

Then, the `\cs_new_protected:Npn` is defined by

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mhchem_regex_peek_compile:Nn #1#2
  {
    \regex_const:Nn #1 { \A the\ (character|letter)\ (#2) \Z }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mhchem_regex_peek:NTF #1#2#3
  {
    \peek_catcode:NTF ##
      {#3}
      {
        \regex_match:NoTF
          #1
          { \token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token } {#2} {#3}
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

And then you need to find out the definitions for these etc.

I included a lot from the `mhchem` package and still was unable to reproduce the command. If you really want tho do it this way, you can look in the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) at ctan, and specificually the [.sty file](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.sty).